# Show some message after updating the android app from play store programmatically

Tags: java, android, kotlin, updating

I am an android developer, I want whenever the user updates the app from the play store a message is shown to the user, or some action is perofrmed.

here is what I have tried,
I used share-preference, but it didn't work.

suggest me what can I do

Comment: "I used shared-preference" can you elaborate what you tried with this ?

Comment: Do you save version name of the app in shared preferences ?

Comment: Have you seen this action?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED